# How to translate one IP address to another IP address within local network?

Tags: networking, translation, router

There are 3 objects at network. Client, Server (PCs) and router.
There is some application on the Client that trying to reach some IP = X (I am not able to change application). That X was the old address of Server in network (DHCP changed it). Now I made the reservation of IP for both server and client. Let's say the new fixed IP of server is Y. 
How can I trick application on client to access Y whenever it tries to acess X? 
One said it is called translation, but I didn't figured out how to implement it.

Comment: i think you can use something like    route add (ip to be translated) (ip to send traffic) into the cmd but this translates every access to the new ip without application filtering, correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solution for Layer 2 devices. That means, if your server and client are on the same switch!
--> IP-Address is only used and needed for routing between Layer 3 devices (Routers).

Try to manipulate the arp-table.

1.) CMD--> "arp -a"
2.) Take a look at the new server ip adress and the corresponding MAC-Adress
3.) Add an ARP entry: arp -s "old ip address" "mac of new ip address".

That could work for some minutes until the arp table gets erased or updated.
Did not try that...you have to :D